# print text between two markers in bash

Tags: bash

I have a following file:

```
$ cat animals

All birds
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Birds in database                 size     date
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pink flamingos                     77       20130830
Black crows                       997       20070122

All mammals
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mammals in database               size     date 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
brown cats                        34        20111201
purple hippos                     23        20120220
white dogs                         9        20130926
black horses                       2        20050428
pink monkeys                     118        19940203

All reptiles
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reptiles in database              size     date 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
red snakes                        44       20070125
green frogs                     1022       20140707

$
```

I would like to print only the content of `Mammals in database` section, i.e. output needs to be:

```
brown cats                        34        20111201
purple hippos                     23        20120220
white dogs                         9        20130926
black horses                       2        20050428
pink monkeys                     118        19940203
```

I could easily do this with `sed`:

```
$ gsed -n '/Mammals in database/,/^$/ { /Mammals in database/N; /Mammals in database/d; /^$/d; p }' < animals
brown cats                        34        20111201
purple hippos                     23        20120220
white dogs                         9        20130926
black horses                       2        20050428
pink monkeys                     118        19940203
$
```

However, is there an elegant way to achieve the same with bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like doing it with `awk`:

```
$ awk '!NF{f=0} NF>3 && f; /Mammals in database/ {f=1}' file
brown cats                        34        20111201
purple hippos                     23        20120220
white dogs                         9        20130926
black horses                       2        20050428
pink monkeys                     118        19940203
```

It is a matter of having a flag `f` and handle it to be on or off depending on the conditions.

---

Pure bash draft approach:

```
var=""
while read -r line
do
   [[ $line =~ ^"All reptiles"* ]] && var=""
   [ "$var" ] && [ "$line" ] && echo "$line"
   [[ $line =~ ^"Mammals in database"* ]] && var=1
done < file
```

#### Test

```
$ while read -r line ; do [[ $line =~ ^"All reptiles"* ]] && var=""; [ "$var" ] && [ "$line" ] && echo "$line"; [[ $line =~ ^"Mammals in database"* ]] && var=1; done < file
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
brown cats                        34        20111201
purple hippos                     23        20120220
white dogs                         9        20130926
black horses                       2        20050428
pink monkeys                     118        19940203
```

Comment: Thanks! However, as I understand, it's not possible to achieve this without external tools like `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: Well, you can really use pure bash for this. However, it may be a bit overkilling, because you will have to write about 10 lines of code for something `awk` can handle quite easily.

Comment: Could you give an example/idea how one can do this in bash?